# Autocomplete rails 4 + jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Boa tarde, pessoal!

tenho o seguinte cenário abaixo:
um model city aonde já estão cadastradas todas as cidades do brasil, e tenho uma view companies aonde vou cadastrar as empresas e quero criar um campo autocomplete para nome da cidade.
Lembrando que o model city e companies não tem nenhuma associação, como eu poderia fazer o campo autocomplete? já tentei uma gem mas não deu certo.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Não existe uma associação, porém existe um campo city na companies como string ? Digo isso em algum lugar você tem que persiste esse value

Comment: Correto Breno, isso existe sim!

Comment: Ok, vou colocar um exemplo aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# você pode usar a gem https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails ou o próprio JS puro.

#### Gemfile adiciona isso

gem "select2-rails"

#### No teu  app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

//= require select2

#### Add to your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

*= require select2

#se você usar o bootstrap adiciona o de baixo senão somente o de cima.

*= require select2-bootstrap

na view adiciona isso no final

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $( ".autocomplete" ).select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
  });
})
</script>
```

no teu form_for
adiciona

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city, City.all, :name, :name, {:class => 'autocomplete'}) %>
```